# мне нужно извлечь из БД нужную таблицу

Tags: android, sqlite

как сделать такчтобы когда я нажимаю на кнопку1 берется значения таблицы1, нажал на кнопку2 значения таблицы2 и т.д.

Я создал 3 таблицы Java, C++, Python в них хранятся данные.

И есть кнопка Java, C++, Pyth в главном mainActivity.

Когда нажимаю на кнопку java переходит на activity2 а там поисковик и я хочу чтобы он искал только по таблице java.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вам надо повесить обработчик на нажатие кнопки, этот обработчик получает view, т.е. вашу кнопку. У кнопки есть id. Соответственно вы можете в обработчике событие нажатии кнопки, проверить какая кнопка была нажата и в соответствии с этим делать нужный запрос к БД. И уже потом вызывать Activity2

```
String dbFromButtonClickHandler;  //ваша переменная с именем таблицы в зависимости от нажатой кнопки
dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
// подключаемся к базе
db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

// проверка существования записей
Cursor c = db.query(dbFromButtonClickHandler, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Вам нужно почитать как делаются запросы к базе данных. В двух словах не объяснить. [вот пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite.html).

Comment: вот мне нужен собственно "нужный запроск БД" ))